# Align data of Itemtemplate inside Gridview

Tags: gridview, alignment, aspxgridview

How can I align data inside the grid view.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
   <%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")) %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it `Gridview` or `ASPxGridview` ?

Answer (score 4):

In your question you have both [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) and [aspxgridview](/questions/tagged/aspxgridview) tags. Anyway, I have answers for both tag.

### For Gridview:

Use [`GridView.RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx) property and set `:horizontal-align`

### For ASPxGridview:

Use [`CellStyle`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewColumn_CellStyletopic) property like;

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn ...>
    <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```